# Laravel factories issues

Tags: laravel

can someone tell me what is wrong with this factory call ...

```
factory('App\User', 9)->create()->each(function ($user){
       $user->posts()->save(factory('App\Post')->make());
    });
```

As you can see I want to make 9 users (since 10th would be my acc made in seeds) and for each of them at least one post.

Here are the issues:

1. If I run these lines of code it will make me 19 users and 9 posts...
   https://prnt.sc/ugiqks
2. Second issue is if I run this exact same lines of code and just add amount of posts I want each user to have for example:

   factory('App\User', 9)->create()->each(function ($user){
   $user->posts()->save(factory('App\Post', rand(1, 5)->make());
   });

so every user can get a random number of posts attached to him I get this issue after running this code
https://prnt.sc/ugir5a

**EDIT** -> Other relevant files

Full code from **DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
public function run()
{
     $this->call(UserSeeder::class);

    factory('App\User', 9)->create()->each(function ($user){
       $user->posts()->saveMany(factory('App\Post', rand(1, 5))->make());
    });
}
```

**UserSeeder.php** code

```
public function run()
{
    User::create([
        'name' => 'Sead Silajdzic',
        'username' => 'sead',
        'email' => 'sead@hotmail.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('password'),
        'slug' => Str::slug('Sead Silajdzic')
    ]);
}
```

**App\User** just relation with Posts

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

**UserFactory**

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {

$name = $faker->name;
$slug = Str::slug($name);

return [
    'name' => $name,
    'slug' => $slug,
    'username' => $faker->userName,
    'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
    'email_verified_at' => now(),
    'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
    'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
];
```

});

**PostFactory**

```
$factory->define(Post::class, function (Faker $faker) {

$title = $faker->sentence;
$slug = Str::slug($title);

return [
    'title' => $title,
    'slug' => $slug,
    'content' => $faker->paragraph,
    'featured' => $faker->imageUrl('900', '480'),
    'user_id' => factory(User::class),
    'category_id' => 1
];
```

});

That is all I guess :)

Comment: probably because on the Post factory you are creating a user

Comment: You mention something about the 10th being something else made in seeds ... I don't really know what you mean by it but 9 + 10 = 19; are you sure you're not making 10 Users somewhere else?

Comment: Another 10 + 9 speculative possibility is that the widget you show uses the highest ID in the users table, rather than the amount of users, and that by "my acc made in seeds" you mean that you created an account with ID 10 and because of that the 9 new ones you make have ID 11, 12, ..., 19

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper I have seeder for my account and it should be 10th acc with these 9 I am trying to generate with factory :) that is 10 users but should be more than 10 posts since all of them should have random from 1 to 5 posts

Comment: So then it'll be the case that Berto99 suggested: 9 users with 9 posts (that then generate 9 more users) + 1 user = 18 + 1 user = 19 users

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper if factories work like that then it is stupid, haha but ty for help :D

Comment: No they don't work like that, you probably specified it somehow ;p

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper I have edited my question with all other relevant files you can check it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last problem you describe, saving multiple posts per user, is because you are trying to use the `save` method to save multiple items. Instead you should be using the [`saveMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method) method when you have an array or collection.

```
factory('App\User', 9)->create()->each(function ($user){
   $user->posts()->saveMany(factory('App\Post', rand(1, 5))->make());
});
```

With the new information gathered from the comments it seems most likely that you are creating a new User for each Post you create in your Post factory.

**Update:** You are creating a new user with this line in the Post factory:

```
'user_id' => factory(User::class),
```

Comment: probably missing a `)` after `rand`

Comment: now I have 34 users and 24 posts instead of 10 users and some amount of posts

Comment: Then it is most likely the case that in your Post factory you are creating another user per post?

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper I will edit my question with all relevant files check it out in few mins :)

Comment: @SeadSilajdzic updated my answer, you were creating a new User in the Post factory with `'user_id' => factory(User::class),`

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper so I can avoid that issue if I don't specify number of users and instead I specify number of posts I want?

Comment: If you ALWAYS want 1 user per post, sure, but it seems like the better thing to do is not specify a `user_id` in your Post factory and to let the `save`/`saveMany` call fill that in for you whenever you use the User factory.

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper but I need user_id for profile and some other things...

Comment: The `save` on `User->posts()->save()` will fill it in! And when you use it on other places you can `factory(Post::class)->make()->each(function($post) { $post->user_id = ...;});`